# PowerShell - datetime format changes

Tags: powershell

I'm having issues formatting the date when using Out-File and Write-Host but format is correct when using $StartDate1.

```
$StartDate1 = ([datetime]::today.AddDays(-1).addhours(00))
$ExchangeOnlineResults = {"Email count for: " + $StartDate1}
& $ExchangeOnlineResults | Out-File  .\test.txt
```

The format is correct when returned in PowerShell:

```
$StartDate1
09 March 2021 00:00:00
```

But Write-Host & Out-File shows:

```
Write-Host $StartDate1
09/03/2021 00:00:00
```

I'm sure this is something basic I am overseeing.

Comment: `[datetime]::today.AddDays(-1).addhours(00).Tostring('dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss')`

Comment: use DateTime script property    $StartDate1 = ([datetime]::today.AddDays(-1).addhours(00)).DateTime

Answer (score 0):

What you are returning in PowerShell is a representation of the object. You need to specify the format you want all that data in when you write to host or save it somewhere. You can inspect the object and see all the various data using `$startDate1 | Get-Member`.

The format types are outlined nicely here by Microsoft:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

The PowerShell way to get and manipulate dates would be like this:

```
(Get-Date).AddDays(-1) | Get-Date -Format 'dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss'
```